# jquery (addClass removeClass) keep form active after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a button.  When the button is clicked it will display a form.  I'm using:

```
  $('#theform').addClass('hidden')  
  $('#theform').removeClass('hidden');
  <div id="theform" class="hidden"><form  method="POST" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);"></form></div>
```

It works fine but when the form is submitted the form disappears.

I've been trying for days to make the form display after submitting but can't find a solution.

My question:  After submitting the form, how can I make the form show (remove .hidden)?

Comment: show you code at jsbin

Comment: Is your form hidden by default? It appears to me that you are not posting it with ajax calls, hence you are refreshing the page (which would bring the page to it's default configuration). If you want to just post it and stay still in your webPage, you should try using the $.ajax or $.post to post that data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var form = $('#theform');

form.submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); //Prevents page from refreshing.
   form.removeClass('hidden');
});
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: It works but the form needs to refresh to display validation errors OR that it was submitted.

Comment: OR is there a way to display PHP validation errors without refreshing?

Answer (score 0):

Extend from @XerxesNoble's post

```
var form = $('#theform');

form.submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); //Prevents page from refreshing.
   if (!validateForm($(this))) { return false; }
   // need to do some actual submission here
   ...

   form.removeClass('hidden');
});
```

another simple solution is you just make the form active by default, then you can still validate and refresh the page

Comment: Ok how do you make the form active by default??  I need to validate that's the reason  e.preventDefault(); doesn't work.

Comment: just remove the `class="hidden"`, that should display the form all the time

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option to 'remove' a hidden, property class and then 'add' a new class that has a visible property. Try:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";

    // maybe serialize an input using ajax
    //var bppxlocation = $('input.bppx-location').val(JSON.stringify(data));
   jQuery(document).ready( function() {
   $( ".bppxLocationForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('#bppxMessage').removeClass('msg-disabled');
       $('#bppxMessage').addClass('msg-active');


       console.log( "class removed ok" );   
    });
});
    
})( jQuery );
```

You may also need to create a timed event using `.delay()` on the new CSS selector in order to get the addClass to do anything productive on or to the page/div. Maybe try an animation to fade out the message div... Maybe try:

```
.msg-active{
left: 0;
opacity: 0;
animation: fadeOut ease 15s;
}
.msg-disabled{
left: -999em;
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
0% {
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
opacity: 0;
}
}
#bppxMessage{ postion: absolute; }
```